# Weird keybindings in Mac OS X Terminal.app

Tags: keyboard, terminal, metadata, emacs

I am trying to use the key "shift-tab" in emacs running purely under Terminal.app, but got an error saying there is no keybinding for "M-[ z" (where M is the meta key, set to be the option key under Terminal.app preferences). In other words, emacs thinks I am pressing "option-[ z" when I pressed "shift-tab" on the keyboard of my MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.6.6, what is the problem and how do I correct it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminal.app is actually doing what it's supposed to:  `shift-TAB` sends `ESC [ z` which Emacs reads as `M-[ z`.  The problem is that the terminal description for `xterm-color` (the one usually used with Terminal.app and other terminal emulators) is missing the `kcbt` declaration, so Emacs doesn't know that that's what the key sends.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Edit the terminal description:

   ```
   $ infocmp >xterm-color.ti
   $ printf '\tkcbt=\E[Z,\n' >>xterm-color.ti
   $ sudo tic xterm-color.ti
   ```
2. Tell Emacs about it directly:

   ```
   $ echo "(global-set-key "\M-[Z" 'something)" >>~/.emacs
   ```

The problem in both cases is that there doesn't seem to be a `backwards-tab` command to substitute for `something`.  Emacs.app binds backtab to `yank`; what do you want it to do?

Comment: I am trying to use "shift-TAB" to cycle through all headings expanded vs closed in emacs org-mode.

Comment: Ok, I don't normally use that, but it has a `<backtab>` binding so you should use the first option (fixing the terminal description to define `<backtab>`).

Comment: If someone is only concerned with “fixing” their one account, then the `sudo` can be omitted to re-compile into `~/.terminfo/`. This will also prevent it from being overwritten by a system update.

Answer (score 3):

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal is more compatible with modern xterm† and therefore the default $TERM value is now xterm-256color, which contains the kcbt entry, eliminating any need to edit the terminfo entry. xterm-color describes an older branch of xterm and is missing a number of things supported by modern xterm.

† Highlights include: Terminal now uses the BCE (Background Color Erase) color model, it supports 256 colors, and the latest xterm-compatible escape sequences for switching to/from the alternate screen buffer.